# Buffer size error iOS Simulator for openAI integration

Tags: javascript, buffer, openai-api

When I deploy my app using npx expo start I get the error seen below on the iOS simulator. I've seen various posts say it's anything from a missing comma, malformed json to "Just change stop: ["\n"] in something different. Worked in my case!" None of these worked in my case.

[image: Buffer error message]

Javascript part of Main.js is below:

```
import { Configuration, OpenAIApi } from "openai";
import { TextInput, TouchableOpacity, View } from "react-native";
const configuration = new Configuration({
    organization: "org-xxxxxxxx",
    apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});
const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);
const response = await openai.listEngines();

const Main = () => {
    const [input, setInput] = useState('')
    const [output, setOutput] = useState('')

    const handleInput = async () => {
        try {
            const userInput = constPrompt + input
            // createCompletion http call to api and get the response 
            const response = await openai.createCompletion({
                model: "text-davinci-003",
                prompt: `You: ${userInput}\nAI:`,
                temperature: 0.2,
                max_tokens: 30,
                top_p: 1.0,
                frequency_penalty: 0.5,
                presence_penalty: 0.0,
                stop: ['You'],
            })
            // use setOutput method from react state to be equal to the response object
            // call data object of the response, nav to choices array, get first element of array and convert it to text. 
            setOutput(response.data.choices[0].text)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
```